# how to apply scrollBar to the form manually in palm application

Tags: javascript, html, css, webos, palm-pre

in my project that is developed using palm technology ie webos ,in this application form is  not get scrolling option automatically,so i have to apply scrollbar manually.with this user can feel userfriendly.could some help me in this isue hoe to apply scrolling manually.
                                    thanking u

Answer (score 0):

A Mojo.Widget.Scroller is available by default in every scene, unless you are manually disabling it.  [Scroller Widget Page](https://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1929&Itemid=307)

It is against WebOS UI standards to have an actual scroll bar or buttons.

If you are using fixed positioning for any of your elements, or don't have content that extends past the bottom of the screen, you may not see scrolling action.